# Python Linked lists AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm trying to write a program to delete duplicate values from a linked list

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None


class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, data):
        node = self.head
        if(node == None):
            self.head = Node(data)
            return
        while(node.next):
            node = node.next
        node.next = Node(data)
        return

def removeDups(ll):
    if(ll.head is None):
        return
    headNode = ll.head
    while(headNode):
        lead = headNode
        while(lead.next):
            if(lead.next.data == headNode.data):
                lead.next = lead.next.next
            lead = lead.next
        headnode = headNode.next
    return

list = LinkedList()

list.append(1)
list.append(2)
list.append(3)
list.append(1)

removeDups(list)
```

The error points to the line at "while(lead.next):" with the Arribute Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Am I not able to assign two values to the same listnode? Are headNode and lead pointers?

Comment: the error comes from here:        while(node.next):
            node = node.next
        node.next = Node(data) ... this class that as you called LinkedList have no Attribute next this attribute is actually exists in Node model try something like: Node().node

Comment: Setting lead to Node(None).lead = headNode didn't fix the problem. Why does lead behave differently from headNode? On headNode I'm able to call headNode.next but lead doesn't work this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. You need two changes in your removeDups function:

```
def removeDups(ll):
    if(ll.head is None):
        return
    headNode = ll.head
    while(headNode):
        lead = headNode
        while(lead and lead.next):
            if(lead.next.data == headNode.data):
                lead.next = lead.next.next
            lead = lead.next
        headNode = headNode.next
    return
```

Comment: Above removeDups should work for your case. Following are the changed lines:


```
while(headNode): =>                  while(lead and lead.next)

headnode = headNode.next => headNode = headNode.next
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you